# Converting yuv 4:2:2 data to UIImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avcapturesession, yuv

I am working on iOS app which will show the video.
The app talks over the Bonjour, Bonjour server is another device which has camera.
The camera capture the images call it as frames for video and send that to iOS over bonjour.

The data that I receive is yuv 4:2:2 data and I need to convert that into UIImage and set to image view.

I looked into "GLCameraRipple" example from apple docs, this code seems to does the trick using GPU.
I am not able to figure out how to give the data that I receive to the delegate method that works to create an image using OpenGL ES.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

This the delegate method of AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and for the further processing the code is using the sampleBuffer of CMSampleBufferRef.

How can I hook this to data that I am getting from bonjour server, so that I can write my own method and will process the data to get the image?